# Selenium select option is unable to use list elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, select

I am trying to select one on a bunch of  options on the list, however I am stuck on finding the element for that list.

here is the html code for that website:

```
<th class="left" nowrap="">
            <select name="position" size="5">  
                <option value="01">One</option>
                <option value="02">Two</option>
                <option value="03">Three</option>
                <option value="04" selected="">Four</option>
            </select>
</th>
```

the default selection on the list is "Four" and trying to select One, but no luck.

I tried using By.Name

```
select_element = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'position')
select = Select(select_element)
select.select_by_visible_text('One')
```

and here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/Documents/selection.py", line 36, in <module>
    select_element = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'position')
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 740, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="position"]; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
```

I also tried using By.CSS_SELECTOR

```
select_element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select')
select = Select(select_element)
select.select_by_visible_text('One')
```

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/Documents/selection.py", line 36, in <module>
    select_element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select')
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 740, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: select; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your given HTML, It's very clear that the options are under a `select` tag. And we can easily choose any options under a select tag using Selenium's `Select` object.

Here's how you may try:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = 'your URL'

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

# Create a Chrome browser instance
browser = Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

# Open the specified URL
browser.get(url)

# switch to the iframe with the ID "customFrame"
browser.switch_to.frame(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe#customFrame'))))

# Find the select tag with the name "position"
select_tag = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'select[name="position"]')))

# Create a Select object for the select tag
position = Select(select_tag)

# Select the option with the value '01'
position.select_by_value('01')

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thank you, however I still have the same error message. Will it be helpful if I tell you that  the select is inside an iframe? Here is the code:
`<iframe id="customFrame" title="testCustomApps" src="forwardservlet?userId=123456789&amp;app=webtest" width="100%" height="100%">
</iframe>`

Comment: if the select is inside an iframe, you first need to switch to the specific iframe first in order to be able to locate or find the desired `select` tag

Comment: @junichironakashima, please check the updated code above